# Select table cells in a column based on the column header text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select the cells in a column based on what text is written in the table column header, e.g., "Status", using `Javascript` or `jQuery`?

(Details, not part of the question: I want to later use this to apply background-color to the cells in that column based on the cell content, so that for example 'Error' would get the background-color red and 'Quality OK' would be white.)

Comment: provide the sample code of your html?

Comment: jQuery `contains()` - https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ - is made for that `$( "th:contains('Status')" ).jquerymethod(...`

Comment: The sample html code as in Adween's answer below looks fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick fiddle i did for you..

http://jsfiddle.net/N2CHt/2/

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Good</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY

```
$(function(){
    var columnindex = $('th:contains("Status")').index();
    if(columnindex != -1)
    {
        $('tr').each(function(){
            var column = $('td', this).eq(columnindex);

            switch(column.text())
            {
                case "Bad":
                    column.css({ backgroundColor: '#900' });
                    break;

                case "Good":
                    column.css({ backgroundColor: '#090' });
                    break;

                default:

                    break;

            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can change the colours and what text you are searching for but you should be able to get a gist of whats going on...

Basically we use the `contains` selector (https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) yp find the `th` that contains the text we are looking for and then `.index()` (http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the columns index. We then loop the tr's using `.each` (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and grab the item using `eq` (https://api.jquery.com/eq/). When then manipulate the css for the `td` and set its background colour property.

One thing to note is that if 2 column `th` text contain "Status" you will face problems!